# Flex Refresh Tree

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I have a mx:Tree with an object as datasource. An array with this structure

```
[ 
  {label: "label1", children: [] },
  {label: "label2", children: [] }
]
```

the problem is: If I add or remove some element (or rename some label) in this array, or in some children of this array, I need to manipulate the tree (open or close some item) to see the change. There is some way to refresh a mx:Tree ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest wrapping your array up in an ArrayCollection.  Then you can call

```
tree.dataProvider.refresh();
```

To force the itemRenderers to refresh themselves.

Just using an array; you may have to replace the dataProvider; conceptually like this:

```
tree.dataProvider = updateArray;
```

It'll work, but may cause a refresh and may not keep all the items open.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and had to reassign the array as a dataProvider to the tree after each change in the array